Is the Euclidean Norm the only function that don't increase the variability?
The errors propagation of a function is defined as:
$$
\Delta f = \Delta f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n, \Delta x_1, \Delta x_2, \dots, \Delta x_n) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \Delta x_i \right)^2}
$$
when the random variables are all the same (iso-variable) and we are concentrating on the propagation of the errors in the function we can state that:
$$
A_f = a \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \right)^2}
$$
where $$ \Delta x_1 = \Delta x_2 = \dots = \Delta x_n = a $$
and Af is the extended uncertainty of the function.
The function under root is nothing more than the Gradient Norm of the function under consideration:
$$
\|\nabla f(x)\| = \sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\right)^2 + \dots + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right)^2\right)}
$$
I found out in my studes that the only function that is self-iso-variable or Af=1 and is not trival is the Norm or, theat is the same, the calulation of the hypotenuse:
$$
√(x^2+y^2 )
$$
I found, for an instance, that following following function is equivalent for the caculation of the hypotenuse is self-iso-variable:
$$
d = \frac{y}{\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)}
$$
but the following not:
$$
d = \frac{y}{\sin(\alpha)}
$$
I'm asking if other functions or geometric constructins have the Af=1 and why the Norm has this unique characteristic.

This is known as the Eikonal equation and it is very well studied

thank you for the answer but as far I can see the Eikonal equation has Af=1 just when S(x) is the Euclidean Norm that was what I already state in my e-mail
